# As model complexity increases, why does the training error increase?

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose I have 3 clusters of data. I train a machine learning model on the combined data set (i.e., 3 clusters of data combined), and the training error decreases as the complexity of the model increases. However, after a certain point, the error increases.

I have a feeling this might be happening because the 3 clusters of data are very different from one another. So it may be "difficult" to fit a model on the "combined" data set when the data is heterogeneous. What might be an intuitive explanation of this phenomenon (i.e., training error increases as model complexity increases)?

Comment: The in-sample error increases, or the error on a validation/test/holdout set increases?

Comment: Have you seen this occur in practice? For model families with sufficient complexity to overfit, you typically see the training error decrease continually with increasing complexity. Eventually, the model is complex enough to just memorize and regurgitate  the training data, resulting in a wildly overfit model with 0 training error.

Comment: In sample error (or training error).